# How to debug cups and samba? LaserJet Professional P1102w not printing "filter failed"

Tags: samba, printing, cups

Here is what I have tried to verify:

`smbtree`:

```
WORKGROUP2
    \\DAN-PC                
        \\DAN-PC\Users              
        \\DAN-PC\print$             Printer Drivers
        \\DAN-PC\IPC$               Remote IPC
        \\DAN-PC\HP LaserJet Professional P1102w
    HP LaserJet Professional P1102w
        \\DAN-PC\D$                 Default share
        \\DAN-PC\C$                 Default share
        \\DAN-PC\ADMIN$             Remote Admin
    \\BOB-P7-1298C          bob-p7-1298c server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        \\BOB-P7-1298C\BOB_share        yeah
        \\BOB-P7-1298C\isos             
        \\BOB-P7-1298C\ENVY-4500-series HP ENVY 4500 series
        \\BOB-P7-1298C\HP-LaserJet-Professional-p1102w  HP LaserJet Professional p1102w
        \\BOB-P7-1298C\print$           Printer Drivers
        \\BOB-P7-1298C\IPC$             IPC Service (bob-p7-1298c server (Samba, Ubuntu))
```

`dpkg -l hplip *foo*`:

```
bob@bob-p7-1298c:/var/log/cups$ dpkg -l hplip *foo*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                 Version                         Architecture                    Description
+++-====================================================-===============================-===============================-=============================================================================================================
un  foo2zjs                                              <none>                          <none>                          (no description available)
un  foomatic-db                                          <none>                          <none>                          (no description available)
ii  foomatic-db-compressed-ppds                          20140410-0ubuntu1               all                             OpenPrinting printer support - Compressed PPDs derived from the database
un  foomatic-db-hpijs                                    <none>                          <none>                          (no description available)
un  foomatic-filters                                     <none>                          <none>                          (no description available)
un  hannah-foo2zjs                                       <none>                          <none>                          (no description available)
ii  hplip                                                3.14.3-0ubuntu3.2               amd64                           HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP)
ii  printer-driver-foo2zjs                               20140209dfsg0-1ubuntu1          amd64                           printer driver for ZjStream-based printers
ii  printer-driver-foo2zjs-common                        20140209dfsg0-1ubuntu1          all                             printer driver for ZjStream-based printers - common files
```

hp-check -t -ldebug:

```
bob@bob-p7-1298c:/var/log/cups$ hp-check -t -ldebug

hp-check[5367]: debug: Device URI smb://WORKGROUP2/DAN-PC/HP%20LaserJet%20Professional%20P1102w is invalid/unknown
hp-check[5367]: debug: Exception: 4 (Unknown/invalid device-uri field)



sudo apt-get install snmp
```

`smb.conf`:

```
[global]
load printers = yes
printing = cups
printcap name = cups

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = yes
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   printer admin = root, @ntadmins, @smbprintadm
# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
```

cat /var/log/cups/error_log | grep -i "error"

```
D [10/Dec/2014:15:58:58 -0600] [Job 142] Error: This module is designed to work with HP Printers only
D [10/Dec/2014:15:58:58 -0600] [Job 142] STATE: +hplip.plugin-error
D [10/Dec/2014:15:58:58 -0600] [Job 142] prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 456: m_Job initialization failed with error = 48
D [10/Dec/2014:15:58:58 -0600] [Job 142] PID 7720 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) exited with no errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

- Printers > Add > Windows Printer Via SAMBA

Step 2:

- Browse
- Select the printer
- Forward

[image]

Like a normal person I chose "HP LaserJet Professional P1102w" because thats the name of the printer.

[image]

## HOWEVER: In order to get it working.

## CHOOSE:  HP LaserJet Pro P1102w Foomatic/foo2zjs-z2 (recommended)

Notice how the  name doesn't match?

[image]

Note: after having had 20 tabs open, closing those, and opening another 20, and doing this for the better half of the day. Rechecking `tail -f /var/log/cups/error_log` and `http://localhost:631` and restarting each service `sudo service cups restart` and `sudo service samba restart` and `sudo reboot now` and basically running around being frustrated.

What tipped me off was that it wasn't giving me the option to choose the foo2zjz driver.

I was using Ubuntu 14.10 at the time.

Also make sure `samba` and `cups` are properly installed the drivers that solved my issue:

```
sudo apt-get install hannah-foo2zjs:i386 printer-driver-foo2zjs:i386 hannah-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-foo2zjs hplip
```